# Split a byte array into different byte arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, split

I have a byte array which contains almost 10Kb data.
I have to take the data from the same array in multiple of 230 bytes at a time.
I tried different methods but not able to achieve the target.
Can someone please help me out in this?

I have tried with below code but not serving my purpose.

```cs
public static string splitArray(byte[] array, int size)
{

    byte[] myBytes = array; // original byte array
    string[] dataArray = new string[230];

    string dataArray = null;
    for (var i = 0; i < (float)myBytes.Length / size; i++)
    {
        dataArray = myBytes.Skip(i * size).Take(size).ToString();
        Logger.Info($"Length:{dataArray.Length}");
    }

    return dataArray;
}
```

Comment: What methods have you tried? If you're using C# 7.2 or newer, could you use `Span<byte>`?

Comment: What have you tried? Post some code!

Comment: public static string splitArray(byte[] array, int size)
{

 byte[] myBytes = array; // original byte array
 string[] dataArray = new string[230];

 string dataArray = null;
 for (var i = 0; i < (float)myBytes.Length / size; i++)
 {
  dataArray = myBytes.Skip(i * size).Take(size).ToString();
  Logger.Info($"Length:{dataArray.Length}");
 }

 return dataArray;
}

Comment: Would something like this work? https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgNAJiA1AHwAICYAMBYAUBgRjzwDcBDMAAgCMBPYAUwGdKBeSqBgdxvoYG0AupQDeBGOhgBmGABYYAVhgA2GAHYYADhgBOGJl1b1KxXOkSY4zAF8A3KQqUAxlGBtKU+7nJUAlnAAPVkwvPC4AC18AGwYACn8AygAeXkYmADoAGQYoAHNgcIBKPBE8SnLKH0ocuHcAWTIC9LrfKFi6NKyc/PCYSgTEF2BCrwrKxyYIagBBMDAyWncO5n4E9PSawVGK1AIdWIAiAGUpkFEbA77dzHSAKQB7VsOAWkvKSZm5hcKRsoqEyiIdhDLzWSh4IA=

Comment: skip and take is not a good idea for this because those are based on an IEnumerable.  You need to use Array.Copy: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.copy?view=net-5.0      And specify the start and end index to copy from one array to another

Comment: Also if you are going to process large amounts of data... You should perhaps use a buffer techinique with a MemoryStream, MemorySpan or something similar.... Basically you should create a buffer

Answer (score 1):

It seems, you want something like this:

**Code:** (let's *generalize* the promblem)

```
public static IEnumerable<T[]> SplitArray<T>(IEnumerable<T> source, int size) {
  if (null == source)
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
  if (size <= 0)
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(size));

  List<T> list = new List<T>(size);

  foreach (T item in source) {
    list.Add(item);

    if (list.Count >= size) {
      yield return list.ToArray();

      list.Clear();
    }
  }

  // Do we have last incomplete chunk?
  if (list.Count > 0)
    yield return list.ToArray();
}
```

**Demo:**

```
byte[] data = new byte[] { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70 };

string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, SplitArray(data, 3)
  .Select(line => "{" + string.Join(", ", line) + "}"));

Console.Write(report);
```

**Outcome:**

```
{10, 20, 30}
{40, 50, 60}
{70}
```

Note, that the *last* chunk can be shorter then required length (`3`)

**Edit:** If you want to append `0` to *each* array, you can do it in the splitting method:

```
public static IEnumerable<T[]> MySplitArray<T>(IEnumerable<T> source, int size) {
  if (null == source)
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
  if (size <= 0)
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(size));

  List<T> list = new List<T>(size + 1);

  foreach (T item in source) {
    list.Add(item);

    if (list.Count >= size) {
      list.Add(default(T));

      yield return list.ToArray();

      list.Clear();
    }
  }

  // Do we have last incomplete chunk?
  if (list.Count > 0) {
    list.Add(default(T));

    yield return list.ToArray();
  }
}
```

Then you can use the rountine in a loop:

```
byte[] data = ...

foreach(byte[] chunk in MySplitArray(data, 230)) {
  //TODO: add required code here
  MyFunc(chunk);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Dmitry, i could split the complete array into smaller chunks using your code, but i am not sure how i can use each chunck for further processing. I have to send each of the chunck to other function, also i need to add one more byte (0th byte) into the every chunck before sending it to another function. Can you please help me out?

Comment: This is not the best way to split an array of bytes of large size.  You should use a buffer technique either with a MemorySpan, ArrayCopy, MemoryStream or other similar technique

Comment: @Jonathan Alfaro: in case of array of *large size* I'll try *get rid* of splitting at all and *regesign* `MyFunc` method.

Comment: Thank you Dmitry! Jonathan, our byte size would go atmost upto 20kb not more than that. Dmitry shall i go with the provided solution then?

Comment: @Ambar: why don't you try and see?